# using hook on OPENFILEW dialog disables resize control

Tags: winapi, dialog, windows-xp, hook

Using this code the resulting dialog box is drawn without ability to be able to be resized by mouse:

```
#include <windows.h>

static UINT_PTR CALLBACK OFNHookProc (HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW);
  ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
  ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
  ofn.lpfnHook = OFNHookProc;
  GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn);
  return 0;
}
```

Removing `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` shows correct dialog window with resize indicator at bottom right corner. How to make dialog that is user-resizeable and with hook procedure ?

(of course that hook is mock here, only to illustrate the error, no matter what I put inside, of course if it is correct on other matters, result is the same)

Comment: Hmya, you are getting the legacy dialog when you enable the hook.  If you want the new resizable one then you have to [use IFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#usage)

Comment: Yes but `IFileDialog` doesn't work in XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `OFN_ENABLESIZING` flag when using `OFN_ENABLEHOOK`.  This is documented behavior:

[OPENFILENAME structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx)

> OFN_ENABLESIZING
>   0x00800000
>   Enables the Explorer-style dialog box to be resized using either the mouse or the keyboard. By default, the Explorer-style Open and Save As dialog boxes allow the dialog box to be resized regardless of whether this flag is set. **This flag is necessary only if you provide a hook procedure or custom template.** The old-style dialog box does not permit resizing.